# how to Open HTTP url WebView in React Native ios

Tags: ios, react-native, webview

I want to open a site that starts with http: //, and it transfers me to https: // please tell me how to solve the problemю
I have a state

```
  this.state = {
     url: 'http://example.com
  };
```

WebVIew

```
  <WebView
        ref={(ref) => {
          this.ref = ref;
        }}
        onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => {
          this.ref.canGoBack = navState.canGoBack;

        }}
        onLoad={(navState) => {
          console.log(navState)
          this.ref.injectJavaScript(`window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(window.localStorage.getItem('session'))`)
        }}
        source={{uri: this.state.url}}
        scalesPageToFit={false}
  />
```

when I open a project on ios, instead of http://example.com, https://example.com opens how to make the URL with http: // open

on android everything is fine

Comment: So what is the problem? Could you add the code you are facing issues with?

Comment: I described in more detail